# Identity Db communicating with Entity Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

I have two databases, the first database is the identity database which I use to register and share user tokens.
My second database is DateDatabase which is a regular database with DbContext. These two databases are in different projects, in the project with DateDatabase there is a reference to the project where the identity database is located. I have some questions related to this configuration

let's say the identity database contains all the data needed to log in, e.g. e-mail, password, etc., and the DateDatabase contains the basic user data, such as the user's first name, last name, profile picture, and so on.

1. where to create database models?
   (in project 1 which has a reference to the IdentityDatabase or where is the Identity database?)
2. how to properly add data to two databases, for example in the Identity database Email, username, password. And in DateDatabase name, surname ...

(I use swagger for this, so after clicking the execute button, I would like these operations to be performed, unless someone has a better way to proceed)

3. How to get specific users for example let's say I want to get users named Tom from Identity database

UserModel (DateDatabase)

```
public class UserModel
    {
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        public string? PhotoUrl { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

UserIdentityModel (identity database )
standard identitytables